# how to connect azure code repository with workday studio?

Tags: azure-devops, version-control, workday-api

I am trying to integrate workday studio with Azure code Repository, inorder to have a version control system.

Please let me know if there is any connector available.

Comment: E-Git plugin for Eclipse is working well with Workday Studio. I was able to setup Azure Repository for my workday studio project.

Answer (score 1):

E-Git plugin for Eclipse is working well with Workday Studio. I was able to setup Azure Repository for my workday studio project